# Make bootable disk/usb in ubuntu 13.10 of windows iso

Tags: usb, windows, live-usb, iso, dvd

I'm using ubuntu 13.10 but i want to install windows so, i downloaded a windows iso 
but how to Make bootable disk/usb in ubuntu 13.10 of windows iso

Answer (score 3):

you can use WinUSB application. To install open your terminal and paste these lines

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

[image]

[Credit Goes Here](http://www.techlw.com/2012/05/create-bootable-windows-usb-in-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 1):

A more complete answer which also includes Ubuntu 14.04 is found here: [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

if you know how, i'ts not even hard:

what you need:

1. Your Windows ISO file
2. A friends PC/Laptop (With Windows installed on it!)
3. an empty USB drive, or CD with at least 4 GB

On your friends PC, download
[Universal USB Installer for Windows](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)
(Do not try to open it in WINE, it will open but that's about it :P)

You should see this:

[image: Universal USB Installer]

Click the I agree button:

[image: Installer]

Select your version of Windows: (for example Windows 7 installer)

Now click the browse button, and locate your .iso file

The last thing is to select the drive you want it to install to, please be careful here, if you select the wrong device, i do NOT know what may happen

at last, click the create button:

[image: installer]

(On my screen it's greyed out, because i didn't select an actual ISO file)

That's it, there you go! if it did not work please tell me, i’ll find you another solution. (I will at least do my best for you XD)

Comment: my all friends use Ubuntu...

Comment: does the solution in the other comment(http://askubuntu.com/a/372971/211999) work for you? if not, i'll try my best for another solution wich can be done from INSIDE Ubuntu :P

Comment: @Coolykoen Try to post solutions that involve Ubuntu.